# How to run Ndk sample app in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

Hi. I want to work on an Augmented Reality application. So I followed this link https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-2-installing-vuforia-sdk and I installed `sdk`, `ndk`, `cygwin`, `vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31` and I set path for all of them but when I run ImageTargets sample app, I'm getting `unsatisfied link exception`. Can anyone suggest me where I did wrong and how to solve that issue.

in my case

**sdk path:** `C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows`
**eclips path:** `C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\eclipse`
**cygwin path:** `C:\cygwin`
**ndk path:** `C:\Development\Android\vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31`
**vuforia-sdk-android path:** `C:\Development\Android\vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31`

**In environment variables I set path to sdk, ndk and cygwin like below:**

```
C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\;
C:\cygwin\bin;
C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r8\
```

Comment: look at my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334041/using-android-studio-with-vuforia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build the native code (C++) by running `ndk-build` command from cygwin command-line. Open up the `Cygwin.bat` in your installation directory to access the command-line and change the directory to the root folder of `ImageTarget` project and run this:

```
ndk-build
```

If it successfully builds the native codes, you should see a `lib` folder added to your project in Eclipse. Now, you may build your APK and run it on your device. You should repeat this step every time you make a change to native codes.

Comment: yes ur right...i did small mistake is before ndk-build excecution i imported my imagetargets app.so i didn't get lib folder.