# Using Android Studio with Vuforia

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio, augmented-reality, vuforia

Here is how I run a Vuforia Sample on Android Studio on Window 8

1. Download, extract sample, remove files .project  and project.properties
2. On Android Studio : Import project, next, next ...
3. Download & install android NDK http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html
4. Download & install cygwin http://cygwin.com/
5. Edit the file jni/Android.mk

   LOCAL_SRC_FILES = C:/Vuforia-sdk/build/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libQCAR.so
   LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := C:/Vuforia-sdk/build/include
   where Vuforia-sdk is your vuforia sdk
6. Open cmd in your project folder and do "ndk-build"
7. In android studio, click on project structure, modules, "YourModuleName", Dependencies, add jars, select the correct path to vuforia sdk for me it was :

   C:\Vuforia-sdk\build\java\QCAR\QCAR.jar
8. build & run your project in Android Studio
9. Have fun!

*Don't forget the PATH variable for the ndk & cygwin

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in this or you are just telling us how to do it?

Comment: I didn't find how to do it, after some research and test, i show you how to do it.

Comment: Where is the jni folder located...I dont find it under the main sample application.. Im having the same problem could you pls help?

Comment: Made the changes so it doesn't stay unanswered. :)

Comment: any idea about installation on mac os x?

Comment: Self-answered questions **have** to contain an actual question and the answer posted as an answer. I've voted to close

Answer (score 7):

Read our Getting Started Guide for instructions on setting up the Java SDK, Android SDK and NDK:

```
 https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/getting-started-android-native-sdk
```

Make sure you have installed the latest version available of Android Studio from:

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
```

Use the Android SDK Manager (from within Android Studio) to get the latest Android SDK and Android Platform and Build tools

Launch Android Studio

Select File - > Import Project ... and browse to the root directory of the 
    sample Vuforia project you want to open
    Proceed in the Import Wizard dialog (click Next, Next) until you reach a     page with this message:

"Alternatively, you can fill in the actual path map in the table below":
    click to edit

enter the actual path to the Vuforia.jar library (which is located under your vuforia_install_dir/build/java/vuforia)

In the Project view, right-click on the Project and expand the view hierarchy so to locate the Vuforia.jar under app > src > main
    right-click on Vuforia.jar to open the context menu

click on the "Add as library..." option in the context menu

Alternatively, if you cannot locate the Vuforia.jar in your project hierarchy:
    right-click on the Project and select "Open Module Settings"

select "App"
   then select the "Dependencies" tab

Click on the "+" button to Add a File Dependency and browse to the Vuforia.jar file

Create a folder called "jniLibs" under the "app/src/main" folder under your Android Studio project directory

Copy the "armeabi-v7a" folder (including the libVuforia.so file located inside it) from the "vuforia_install_dir/build/lib" to the "app/src/main/jniLibs" folder

```
the resulting directory structure under your project root should be:
/app
/src
/main
/jniLibs
/armeabi-v7a
libVuforia.so
```

Clean and rebuild the project

Run the app on your device

Comment: For the anyone with the problem: "the library libvuforia.so could not be loaded", creating the jniLibs folder structure saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: @user1907954 helped me as well!

Comment: For anyone having trouble where trying to open any Vuforia-based part of the sample app would make the screen flash and just throw you back into the Activity selection screen, the jniibs+armeabi part fixed it

Comment: This looks like something you copied from somewhere else. Do you have a link to the original source? Where did you get it from? @dhana-sekaran

Comment: @MDragon00  - Check your Vuforia Key once...

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
Exporting Eclipse Project with vuforia into Android Studio, which worked for me.

Below are the steps which i followed to the project work fine in Android Studio.

- Export the Eclipse project from Eclipse as a Gradle project.
- Go to the welcome to android studio  window in android studio.
- Click on Import Non android studio project.
- Locate the project that you exported  from eclipse, expand it and select the `build.gradle` file and click ok.
- Copy the `vuforia.jar` file from the vuforia sdk.
- Right click on the project in android studio and click on Show in Explorer option.
- Locate the `libs` folder and paste the copied `vuforia.jar` file.
- Make a folder `lib` ( NOTE: it is not libs) in the same structure as APK file.
- Make another folder `armeabi` inside `lib` folder.
- Copy `.so` files and paste it inside `armeabi` folder. and zip the lib folder into `lib.zip`
- Rename the `lib.zip` to `armeabi.jar`
- Include the `armeabi.jar` inside `libs` folder.
- Then clean build and run the project.