# Incorporate vuforia android SDK in a new project

Tags: android, vuforia, loadlibrary

I want to use vuforia sdk's text recognition module in my new app.

I have been successful in building and running their sample apps. However, having done that was apparently not enough for me to figure out how to start using vuforia android sdk in my mew project in a proper way.

The IDE is Android Studio. I have the license key for my vuforia account.

Could someone help me get started? I jist need to start using vuforia as a library in my own personal project. I do not want to start developing directly over their sample apps.

I am sorry if the context of the questions doesn't fit into that of this particular community.

Comment: Honestly i have just been able to run their sample apps. But having done that was not enough for me to set up the library for my own project.

Comment: Suggestions so far have been to use their sample apps and build over them. But my project requires that i do it all on my own, using Vuforia, so that i have control over my project

Comment: Have you followed these links?:  https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Installing-the-Vuforia-Android-SDK  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334041/using-android-studio-with-vuforia.  At what point have you struggled?

Comment: I have downloaded and unpacked vuforia SDK in the same places as my android sdk and ndk. Next, i am unfamiliar with the QCAR stuff. Also btw, i am using Android Studio.
Additionally, i cannot find exhaustive documentation for using the sdk from scratch. All the resources are for working out with samples. Is it by any chance, that the only options is to use wanted modules from their samples?

Comment: Vuforia SDK API reference may be found here: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/api-list. The best way to get familiar with it is to follow their example and understand how it works, and then modify it according to your needs or take the relevant parts to your app. If you have more specific questions, please ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on Vuforia's module, I built my own real-time OCR from scratch, using the Camera (1) API and Google's Mobile Vision Library.

My app - [Optical Dictionary & Vocabulary Teacher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abdulwasaetariq.odnvt) - performs a lot better than Vuforia's module. It does real-time scanning of words, shows them in a more friendly manner, and does way better validation of words. It even lemmatizes the words (e.g fooled -> fool, thieves -> thief etc).

Also, needless to say that this gave me complete control over my module as well.

Here is a [Video Demo](https://youtu.be/0jxNk7Z5p2E) of my app.

If any one wants to build something similar, they can feel free to contact me for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do exactly what you said. I didn't want to build on the top of their samples. I struggled to find a tutorial but there is none, at least I was not able to fine one. Turns out it is really easy. Go to the Vuforia folder(wherever you installed it) and then head to vuforia-sdk-android-X-XX-X\build\java\vuforia and copy the .jar file and paste that file to your new project in Android studio inside your libs folder. Then add this line to your Build.Gradle

```
compile files('libs/Vuforia.jar')
```

inside your dependencies. That's it. You can access all the Vuforia classes from there. Don't forget to instanciate them just like in the example with your own key from Vuforia developer console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but... This link shows what you need to do, code-wise, for creating a new Vuforia App: [How can I build a basic Vuforia app](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/android-how-can-i-build-basic-vuforia-app). This, along with the links you have already seen regarding the setup, should be enough for you to get started from scratch.