# Vuforia SDK Examples Not Running - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to run Vuforia SDK samples from [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples) on Android:

I have already downloaded the main SDK and put those sample files in the sample folder. I have added the Vuforia.jar as a library and dependency to my project. The app runs on my Samsung S4 and shows the Menu but when I click Start on any of the examples it sends me back to the main menu rather than opening the camera. It doesn't show any crash error in the logs.

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this problem and has managed to fix it?

Comment: I've ran into problems that the camera intent for Samsung devices just doesn't work as expected. Make sure you followed this https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Installing-the-Android-SDK-for-Android-Studio

Comment: @cricket_007 Hmm that link is just a general installation guide :-/

Comment: Right. Just providing a link for those unfamiliar with the library you are using

Comment: Please refer this link..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334041/using-android-studio-with-vuforia

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and when looked at the log it had this message com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples W/System.err: The library libVuforia.so could not be loaded

Then I followed the answer here https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/crash-start-button-sample
and that .jar file to the project. This solved the above issue.

Also I had to generate a license key for the app and set it in the last parameter in Vuforia.setInitParameters(mActivity, mVuforiaFlags, "") in the SampleApplicationSession class

Answer (score 0):

try it:

1. add the Vuforia.jar lib in your project;
2. go to archive build.gradle (Module:app) and check if the variable 'VUFORIA_SDK_DIR' is correct (in my project it had the value "../../../" but i had to change to "../../"), the path has to lead to your Vuforia SDK dir;
3. finally, change the method Vuforia.setInitParameters in the archive SampleApplicationSession.java (line: 414), add your vuforia key in the third paramether;

it works to me