# Can I link a Vuforia app with android app?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I'm working on an app which needs `augmented reality`, so I'm asking if I can create my app on `android studio` then link it with `vuforia application` which is made by unity if so, I'd like to know how, if I can't , is there other ways?

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Android Studio with Vuforia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334041/using-android-studio-with-vuforia)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the steps to do that:
Setting Up the Android Development Environment, install these components in the following order:

1- JDK (Java SE)

2- Android Studio IDE

3- Android SDK packages

4- Cygwin environment

5- Android NDK

then install the Vuforia Android SDK

here is the details:
https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Getting-Started-with-Vuforia-for-Android-Development

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.